# NoScript ABE Not Working - Why?

Tags: firefox-extensions, noscript

I have lately been trying to allow certain scripts only for certain sites via NoScript ABE. Specifically, I want to:

- Allow some scripts from Google everywhere
- Allow some scripts from Google only on Google's sites (e.g. for Google drive/docs)
- Allow scripts from Facebook only on Facebook

I can't get any of these to work. I'm fairly certain Facebook should because I took the example almost directly from [NoScripts documentation on Abe](https://noscript.net/abe/):

```
Site .facebook.com .fbcdn.net .akamaihd.net
Accept from .facebook.com .fbcdn.net .akamaihd.net
Deny INCLUSION(SCRIPT, OBJ, SUBDOC)
```

The only change I've made is to add .akamaihd.net, though it doesn't work without that either. Here is a screenshot of my settings in case I've done something really dumb like put it in the wrong section:

[image: ABE settings screenshot]

Creating a fresh Firefox profile, installing NoScript and trying the rules there has the same result so I don't think the issue is another addon or a Firefox misconfiguration. I am running 64 bit Firefox 35.0.1 on Fedora 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain rules you listed are fine - have you tried whitelisting the site & seeing if ABE calls are being matched?

***Detailed answer:***

ABE operates independently of NoScript. As it was intended to restrict unwanted/dangerous behavior of scripts/sites that are already running scripts, it will simply not run unless you have the site whitelisted.

So as a first step in testing ABE rules, whitelist the site.

After the site is whitelisted & a rule is written, you may (like me) be wary that without seeing some sort of confirmation, scripts from other sites will run. Thankfully, ABE logs all matches to the Error Console, from which you can confirm that a rule was matched and a resulting request was blocked/allowed.

Unfortunately, this type of logging is deprecated in FireFox - in order to enable the error console, go to about:config and set devtools.errorconsole.enabled to ***true***. Then you can pull up the error console from the tools menu, & watch ABE in action. See [this MDN article here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Error_Console).

If things are going as planned, you will see something like this (ABE denying a script call to twitter.com from newsweek.com):

[image: ABE in action]

Comment: I totally forgot about this question! I have had this working for a while and it was, as you said, just that I hadn't whitelisted it. The information about why and how to test ABE rules is news to me though and I wish I could upvote this twice.